# Function to send GET requests in LoadRunner using .h library?

Tags: c, web-services, get, loadrunner, c-libraries

I have script in LoadRunner, which sends POST requests using functions in .h library.

I must write new function and add it to .h library to have possibility to send GET requests to web-service in LoadRunner.

Could you tell me any idea, how to do this?

Comment: look at [httping code](http://www.vanheusden.com/httping/)

Comment: I already answered on the other thread. You need only to change "Method  = POST" to "Method = GET" in the web_custom_request call. No need to write anything new in .h files.

Comment: Should I write this syntax?

web_custom_request(transname,
URL,
"Method=GET",
"TargetFrame=",
"Mode=HTML",
"Resource=0",
"Referer=",
EncodingType,
lr_eval_string(request),
LAST);

is it enough?

Comment: Or may be, should I write this way:

web_custom_request(transname,
URL,
"Method=GET",
lr_eval_string(request),
LAST);

and in user_init additionaly change URL, i.e. include after host name in URL required parameters for server?

Which way is the best?